# How to align entry and label in the same row within a scrollable frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code is using a vertical scrolled frame (from [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/VerticalScrolledFrame)).  Currently "Name:Ryan", and the entry box are not aligned in the same row. I wanted to align the entry box and the label so they are on the same column, and I messed around with the `pack()` method but I was not able to fix it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    class SampleApp(Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            root = Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.label = Label(text="Choose the info to exclude (if any) on the \n left." 
                                    "Write the number of the  tags that should \n be associated with the information on the right.")
            self.label.pack()

            self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(root)
            self.frame.pack(side=LEFT)


            self.frame2=VerticalScrolledFrame(root)
            self.frame2.pack()

            buttons = []
            resource=[]
            for i in range(10):
                buttons.append(Checkbutton(self.frame.interior, text=str(i)+". "+ "Button" ))
                buttons[-1].pack()

            label=[]
            for i in range(10):
                resource.append(Entry(self.frame2.interior, width=3))
                label.append(Label(self.frame2.interior,text="Name: Ryan"))
                label[-1].pack()
                resource[-1].pack()


    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: Output:]

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to lay things out in a grid,  your best choice is to use `grid` rather than `pack`.

For example:

```
self.frame2.interior.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
for i in range(10):
    resource.append(Entry(self.frame2.interior, width=3))
    label.append(Label(self.frame2.interior,text="Name: Ryan"))
    label[-1].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="e")
    resource[-1].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky="ew")
```

Comment: His VerticalScrolledFrame calls `.pack()` internally. Doesn't this mean that he'll be mixing `.grid()` and `.pack()` in the same window? Isn't that a bad thing?

Comment: @Robᵩ: no, because it doesn't call `pack` for widgets _inside_ of the interior frame. self.frame2.interior is completely under control of the caller.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, `.grid()` is obviously a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating intermediate frames in which to hold each row, like so:

```
class SampleApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        root = Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = Label(text="Choose the info to exclude (if any) on the \n left."
                                "Write the number of the  tags that should \n be associated with the information on the right.")
        self.label.pack()

        self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(root)
        self.frame.pack()


        buttons = []
        resource=[]
        label=[]
        for i in range(10):
            frame = Frame(self.frame.interior)
            frame.pack(side=TOP)

            buttons.append(Checkbutton(frame, text=str(i)+". "+ "Button" ))
            resource.append(Entry(frame, width=3))
            label.append(Label(frame,text="Name: Ryan"))

            buttons[-1].pack(side=LEFT)
            label[-1].pack(side=LEFT)
            resource[-1].pack(side=LEFT)
```

Stack the frames into a column using `side=TOP`, and arrange the contents of each frame into a row using `side=LEFT`.

[image]

Comment: this won't work very well if the length of each label is different.